# fetch() fails in Firefox with SSL client authentication

Tags: javascript, firefox, ssl

I have a web server which uses SSL client authentication. A web page on that server makes a same-origin `GET` request using the `fetch()` API.

In Chrome, the client cert is sent in the SSL handshake, as expected, resulting in a 200 "ok" response. In Firefox, the cert isn't sent, resulting in a 403 "forbidden" response.

In Firefox, if I switch it from using `fetch()` to `XMLHttpRequest`, it works. If I load the same URL directly from Firefox's URL bar, it works. The problem seems limited to `fetch()` on Firefox.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there any way to make `fetch()` play well with SSL client auth in Firefox, or do I need to switch to using `XMLHttpRequest` everywhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just solved my own problem. This is what was failing:

```
fetch(someUrl)
```

This fixes the issue:

```
fetch(someUrl, { credentials: 'include' })
```

Apparently there's different behavior here between Chrome (v54) and Firefox (v45).

Comment: Thanks, I recently switched to Firefox and couldn't understand why my site that uses client side cert authentication just wasn't working. This fixes it!